# Invalid integrating factor for $(4-x^2)\dfrac{dy}{dx}-xy+1=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is:
$(4-x^2)\dfrac{dy}{dx}-xy+1=0$ where $|x|\leq 2$.
and I calculated and get $I(x)=(x^2-4)^{1/2}$. However, the $I(x)$ is invalid because $x^2<4$ and it has no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$\mu(x) = \exp\left(-\int{x\, dx\over 4 - x^2}\right)
= \exp\left(1/2\log|4 - x^2|\right) = \sqrt{|4 - x^2|}.$$

Comment: got it, thanks!